# Apollo GraphQL Deconstruction of data not working

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am digging `graphql` so I followed a tutorial, And I stucked in this part.

**Home.js**

```
function Home() {
  const {
    loading,
    data: { getPosts: posts }   // <===## Here ##
  } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

  return (
      <div>
        {loading ? (
          <h1>Loading posts..</h1>
        ) : (
          posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <p>
              {post.content}
            </p>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
  );
}

const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    getPosts {
      id
      content
    }
  }
`;


export default Home;
```

**resolver**

```
  Query: {
    async getPosts() {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });
        return posts;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    }
  },
```

Whole code: https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-graphql-mern-apollo/tree/react10

In above example is working well, and it use it use `data: { getPosts: posts }` for deconstruction of returned data. but In my code, I followed it but I got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined

Instead, If I code like below,

```
function Home() {
  const {
    loading,
    data // <===## Here ##
  } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

  if(loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

  const { getPosts: posts } = data // <===## Here ##

  return (
      <div>
        {loading ? (
          <h1>Loading posts..</h1>
        ) : (
          posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <p>
              {post.content}
            </p>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
  );
}
```

It working well. Seems like my code try to reference `data` before it loaded. But I don't know why this happen. Code is almost same. Different things are `1. my code is on nextjs`, `2. my code is on apollo-server-express`. Other things are almost same, my resolver use `async/await`, and will return `posts`. Am I miss something?

my resolver is like below.

```
 Query: {
    async getPosts(_, { pageNum, searchQuery }) {
      try {
        const perPage = 5
        const posts =
          await Post
            .find(searchQuery ? { $or: search } : {})
            .sort('-_id')
            .limit(perPage)
            .skip((pageNum - 1) * perPage)
        return posts
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your tutorial may be out of date. In older versions of Apollo Client, `data` was initially set to an empty object. This way, if your code accessed some property on it, it wouldn't blow up. While this was convenient, it also wasn't particularly accurate (there is no data, so why are we providing an object?). Now, `data` is simply undefined until your operation completes. This is why the latter code is working -- you don't access any properties on data until after `loading` is false, which means the query is done and `data` is no longer undefined.

If you want to destructure `data` when your hook is declared, you can utilize a default value like this:

```
const {
  loading,
  data: { getPosts: posts } = {}
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY)
```

You could even assign a default value to `posts` as well if you like.

Just keep in mind two other things: One, `data` will *remain* undefined if a network error occurs, even after `loading` is changed to `true`, so make sure your code accounts for this scenario. Two, depending on your schema, if there's `errors` in your response, it's possible for your entire `data` object to end up null. In this case, you'll *still* hit an issue with destructuring because default values only work with undefined, not null.